# What are the Qt ownership rules?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have three classes - `Main`, `A` and `B` with the following definitions:

```
class Main : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    A* a;
public:
    explicit Main(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent), a(new A(this)) {}

    Q_INVOKABLE A* getA() { return a; }
    Q_INVOKABLE B* getB() { return new B(); }
}

class A : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit A(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}
}
// class B has the same definition as A
```

Main class is a singleton responsible for handling interactions between C++ objects and QML, so I set it as a context property.

```
Main* main = new Main();
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("main", main);
```

Now, I want to access objects A and B in QML (JavaScript function).

```
function ownershipTest() {
    let a = main.getA()
    let b = main.getB()
    // do something with these objects
}
```

The question is, what happens with these objects when the function returns?

I think that object `A` should stay in memory because it is owned by Main. Object `B` should be deleted because it has no parent, so QML should assume ownership.

Is my understanding correct? Are there more rules regarding Qt ownership which I should know?

Comment: Did you read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html ? There is a section about ownership.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I did but the section is very brief and lacks concrete examples.

Comment: But I find it quite clearly states that your `A` object will be C++-owned and `B` will be QML-owned

Comment: You can try adding debug statements in the destructor and check

Comment: @Gurushant Thanks, that should be a good way to verify it.